# R-taking reverse of substring of strsplit sentence

Tags: r

I have a sentence, ['this', 'is, 'my', house'].
After splitting it by using "-"as a as separator,and reversing it to[ house, my, is, this], how do I access the last part of string? and join my and is together with house to form another sentence?

Comment: When you say " reverse of the last string"  do you mean you want "esuoh"?

Comment: @G5W, Yes, I need reverse of house and 'esuoh' should be the first word of the new sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentence <- c("this","is","my","house")
strsplit(sentence[4], split="")[[1]][nchar(sentence[4]):1]
```

This code might be a bit dense for a beginner to interpret. The `[[1]]` is necessary because the value of `strsplit` is always a list, even when it's just one vector of individual characters; the indexing extracts that vector. The indexing after that, `[nchar(sentence[4]):1]`, reorders the letters in that vector backwards, from the last to the first, in this case `c(5,4,3,2,1)`. The `split=""` argument causes the `strsplit` function to split the string at every possible point, i.e. between each character.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

```
out <- strsplit(sentence, "-")
last <- out[length(out)]
flip <- rev(last)
word <- paste(flip, collapse='')
```

Comment: @Rich, it is not giving me esuoh but it is giving me 'house' I tried it just now